# Exclude AutoGeneratedProgram.cs from code coverage

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure Devops, I've noticed that in one of our test projects the `AutoGeneratedProgram.cs` is being generated but I want to exclude this from code coverage.

The Test Project has `TargetFramework` of `net6.0`

The version of `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` installed is version `16.11.0`

I found the following thread but it dates back from 2017:
https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/813

Apparently it's fixed but I don't think it is. I'm unable to find any recent examples / solutions regarding the issue.

Can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 0):

Came across this today, one way to do this would be in the pipeline using filters:

| Option | Summary |
| --- | --- |
| Format | Coverage output format. These are either cobertura, json, lcov, opencover or teamcity as well as combinations of these formats. |
| Exclude | Exclude from code coverage analysing using filter expressions. |
| ExcludeByFile | Ignore specific source files from code coverage. |
| Include | Explicitly set what to include in code coverage analysis using filter expressions. |
| IncludeDirectory | Explicitly set which directories to include in code coverage analysis. |
| SingleHit | Specifies whether to limit code coverage hit reporting to a single hit for each location. |
| UseSourceLink | Specifies whether to use SourceLink URIs in place of file system paths. |
| IncludeTestAssembly | Include coverage of the test assembly. |
| SkipAutoProps | Neither track nor record auto-implemented properties. |
| DoesNotReturnAttribute | Methods marked with these attributes are known not to return, statements following them will be excluded from coverage |
| DeterministicReport | Generates deterministic report in context of deterministic build. Take a look at documentation for further informations. |
| ExcludeAssembliesWithoutSources | Specifies whether to exclude assemblies without source. Options are either MissingAll, MissingAny or None. Default is MissingAll. |

see: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonerdo/coverlet/master/Documentation/VSTestIntegration.md

for more info.

for example:
/p:ExcludeByAttribute="TestSDKAutoGeneratedCode"